# svnversion does not match repository browser?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, version

I'm trying to get the the version number of my code to include in deployment file, but I'm running into a strange situation.  I'm not a very avid user of svn so I may be missing some svn subtlety here.

When I run `svnversion` on the root of my project, or `svnversion c:\dev\calculator` where c:\dev\calculator is the root of my source code, I get the same result: 17597.

```
C:\Dev\Calculator>svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 17597.

C:\Dev\Calculator>svnversion
17597 

C:\Dev\Calculator>svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: C:\Dev\Calculator
URL: http://10.168.130.30:8080/read_only/Trunk/Calculator
Repository Root: http://10.168.130.30:8080/read_only
Repository UUID: 9bacaef-544f-534e-b388-4c9dd7c52319
Revision: 17597
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: domain\user
Last Changed Rev: 17544
Last Changed Date: 2012-07-19 15:00:36 -0400 (Thu, 19 Jul 2012)
```

However, when I use TortoiseSVN Repository Browser, I see the Revision column for my "Calculator" folder at 17544.  Furthermore, doing a log on the 'Calculator' folder shows me the last log entry at rev 17544 and [the revision graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGlIC.jpg) also confirms this.

Why the discrepancy?  Where is the 17597 number coming from?  What is the difference between `Last Changed Rev` and `Revision`?

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Revision: 17597
```

Shows the current revision of the **working copy**, that is the identifier associated to the current state of your whole versioned project.

```
Last Changed Rev: 17544
```

Shows the revision at which the targeted **working directory** contents (including subfolders) have been changed the last time.

In your case you called `svn info [TARGET[@REV]...]` without the optional `target` parameter, from `C:\Dev\Calculator>` folder.

If a `target` parameter is not specified `svn info` selects as target the **current directory**, in your case `C:\Dev\Calculator>`.

So `svn info` is telling you that the latest revision at which `\trunk\Calculator` contents have been modified is `rev. 17544`.

You should note that even if you are calling `svn info` on the working directory mapped to the **trunk** folder of the svn repository you could have some more recents revisions on **branches** or **tags**.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  17544 is the last rev available for this folder.  Are you saying that the rev 17597 will increment for this project even if changes are made in folders external to "Calculator" folder?  My repo structure shows: Trunk/BackEnd, Trunk/BC, Trunk/Calculator - where BackEnd, BC and Calculator are 3 independent projects.  Does that mean whenever someone commits something to the BC project, that the rev for the Calculator project will increment?  That doesn't sound "right".

Comment: Yes, Subversion revision numbers are global to the entire repository. Any commit anywhere in the hierarchy will update the global revision. `svn update` brings the working copy up to date with the global revision, but the most recent local change may have occurred on an earlier revision.

Comment: Is there any way to get the latest revision number for a particular folder?  It would seem a little counter-intuitive to me at least that versions 1000-2000 of a particular folder may be identical because some file in a completely other non-related project (although in the same repo) was updated.

Comment: The way to get the latest revision number for a particular folder is exactly svn info, giving that folder as a parameter. Edited my answer trying to be clearer. Thanks ChrisH for your comment.